# trying to send a an embed message based on event event

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

i'm trying to make a logger for deleted messages based on an event whenever the message is deleted

```
snipe_message_author = None
snipe_message_id = None

@client.event
async def on_message_delete(message):

    global snipe_message_content
    global snipe_message_author
    global snipe_message_id

    snipe_message_content = message.content
    snipe_message_author = message.author.id
    snipe_message_id = message.id
    await asyncio.sleep(60)

    if message.id == snipe_message_id:
        snipe_message_author = None
        snipe_message_content = None
        snipe_message_id = None


@client.event
async def logs(ctx, message):
    if snipe_message_content==None:
        m == 1
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{snipe_message_content}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Sniped by {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}")
        embed.set_author(name= f"<@{snipe_message_author}>")
        await message.channel.send(client.get_channel('channel id'), embed=embed)
        return
```

I'm encountering problems with this part....

```
@client.event
async def logs(ctx, message):
    if snipe_message_content==None:
        m == 1
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{snipe_message_content}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Sniped by {message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}")
        embed.set_author(name= f"<@{snipe_message_author}>")
        await message.channel.send(client.get_channel('channnelid'), embed=embed)
        return
```

I've tried using different methods but none have been working so far

Comment: what problem do you have ? Do you get error message? always put full error message (stating at word "Traceback") in queston (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You need a command?

```py
@client.command()
async def logs(ctx):
    global snipe_message_content
    if snipe_message_content==None:
        m = 1
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"{snipe_message_content}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Sniped by {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}")
        embed.set_author(name= f"<@{snipe_message_author}>")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: No, I already have a command for that the "s" and "snipe", I need an event in which if a message was deleted, it sends an embed link with the content in it without me actually using the command that's why i said "event" and not command

Comment: then add the code in `on_message_delete` event itself, you can't make your own events